# toggle script trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on a toggle script but I find myself repeating my code, is there a way of combining it all? I am new to jquery , so forgive me my beginner question.

here is what I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var topContainer = $("#alles");  
    var topButton = $(".abutton"); 
    topButton.click(function() {
        topContainer.slideToggle(1200, 'easeInOutQuart');
        $(".hideable").slideToggle(1200, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }); 

    var topContainer2 = $("#voorbeelden");  
    var topButton2 = $(".bbutton"); 
    topButton2.click(function() {
        topContainer2.slideToggle(1200, 'easeInOutQuart');
        $(".hideable").slideToggle(1200, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }); 

    var topContainer3 = $("#contact");  
    var topButton3 = $(".cbutton"); 
    topButton3.click(function() {
        topContainer3.slideToggle(1200, 'easeInOutQuart');
         $(".hideable").slideToggle(1200, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }); 
});
```

I have learned never to repeat yourself while writing css, must be true for jquery as well, right?

thanks people,
J.

Comment: This can't really be done in jquery, but you could write your own loop or function to do this.

Comment: Perfectly doable if their parent is easily found with a standard method for all 3 (i.e. immediate parent, or first parent with class of "container", etc)

Comment: no the thing is it are three different items which are toggled by three different buttons

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: This is not obvious from OP's code.

Comment: How would you select the container from the button? Is the container just a div wrapping the button?

Comment: @simonzack I know, that's why I said "if" - implicitly explaining how to make it possible for the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull the code out into a re-useable function.

```
function bindStuff(containerId, buttonClass){
    var topContainer = $("#" + containerId);  
    var topButton = $("." + buttonClass); 
    topButton.click(function() {
        topContainer.slideToggle(1200, 'easeInOutQuart');
         $(".hideable").slideToggle(1200, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }); 
}

bindStuff("alles", "abutton");
bindStuff("voorbeelden", "bbutton");
/* ... */
```

Another (probably better) option would be to re-think your naming.  Use shared classes and then bind it all as one.  I would need to better understand your html to make a full suggestion though.

You might consider posting more of your code at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: good one, here it is: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31367/toggle-script-trouble

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could make a function that takes the appropriate parameters.

```
function attachHandlers(element, attachment) {
    element = $(element);
    attachment = $(attachment);

    element.click(function() {
        attachment.slideToggle(1200, 'easeInOutQuart');
        $('.hideable').slideToggle(1200, 'easeInOutQuart');
    }
}
```

Then you simply call attachHandlers with everything you care about. Do this within document.ready()

```
attachHandlers('.abutton', '#alles');
attachHandlers('.bbutton', '#voorbeelden');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your function, add the same class to your buttons so you can all select them all by one selector and then iterate over result and assign your function to each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your naming conventions make sense, and your `container` elements are actually containers of the buttons:

```
$(".abutton, .bbutton, .cbutton").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().slideToggle(1200, 'easeInOutQuart');
    $(".hideable").slideToggle(1200, 'easeInOutQuart');
})
```